# How can I add a magnifying glass to my website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm a junior developer in charge of developing a website for elderly people using Django. My idea was to add a button that when you click it it generates a magnifying glass that biggens the words. Unfortunately I couldn't find any clear code related to this. Could anyone give me some clues about how to do this? It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

most magnifying tools are only used for picture zoom.

I found something for you, which can zoom the text aswell

```
<p><strong>Text Demo</strong></p>

<div id="zoom1">

  <div class="small">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- the clone option will automatically make a div.large if it doesn't exist -->

</div>
```

JavaScript + jQuery 3.1.0

```
/* 
 Demo for jQuery AnythingZoomer Plugin
 https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingZoomer
 */
$(function() {
  $("#zoom1").anythingZoomer({

    // ***************** content areas *****************
    // class of small content area; the element with this class
    // name must be inside of the wrapper
    smallArea: 'small',

    // class of large content area; this class must exist inside
    // of the wrapper. When the clone option is true, it will add
    // this automatically
    largeArea: 'large',

    // Make a clone of the small content area, use css to modify
    // the style; default is false;
    // set to true here to clone the small content
    clone: true,

    // ***************** appearance *****************
    // Set to true to add the overlay style while hovering the
    // small content, false to disable
    overlay: false,

    // fade animation speed (in milliseconds)
    speed: 100,

    // How far outside the wrapped edges the mouse can go;
    // previously called "expansionSize"
    edge: 30,

    // adjust the horizontal position of the large content inside
    // the zoom window as desired
    offsetX: 0,

    // adjust the vertical position of the large content inside
    // the zoom window as desired
    offsetY: 0,

    // ***************** functionality *****************
    // event that allows toggling between small and large
    // elements; default is double click ('dblclick')
    switchEvent: 'dblclick',

    // time to delay before revealing the zoom window.
    delay: 0,

    // ***************** edit mode *****************
    // add x,y coordinates into zoom window to make it easier to
    // find coordinates
    edit: false,

    // ***************** callbacks *****************
    // AnythingZoomer done initializing
    initialized: function(e, zoomer) {},

    // zoom window visible
    zoom: function(e, zoomer) {},

    // zoom window hidden
    unzoom: function(e, zoomer) {}

  });

  $("#zoom2").anythingZoomer();
});
```

CSS:

```
/* Text Demo */
.large p {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.small p {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 8px;
}

/* Image Demo */
.large img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 333px;
}

.small img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Dark overlay - set overlay option
 to true to see this style */
.az-overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  z-index: 10;
}
/* make zoom window round 
  default zoom window size is 110px,
  set the border-radius to half */
.az-zoom {
  border-radius: 5px; /* 55px; */
}

/* fade out small content when hovering
.az-hovered > * {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
*/

.large {
  background: #fff;
}

.zoom {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

you will need to put everything inside the zoom1 class and make a button, which activates the JavaScript function.

I hope i could help you a little

Answer (score 1):

Usually zooming apis are made for images and zooming texts can sometimes be tricky.

I suggest that you use something like
[AnythingZoomer](https://css-tricks.github.io/AnythingZoomer/use.html)
or
[Zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/).

You can take a look at their documentation and try implementing it.